# Array Needed To Sum Unique ID

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am running into an issue with arrays returning "The resulting array was too large". I have looked around and just stumped on this. I know the issue is related to the MMULT formula I am using.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VZXBS8hk-aExzi3KO4WpZEsm8BivyH1De_qAPQI7vmA/edit?usp=sharing

I have a block of data listing Products per worker, if that product is active, and a location id. A summary per location is needed to see active product per location. I have something that works but when using it on 7000 line items it errors out with "The resulting array was too large".

Does anyone have an alternative to H3 in the above sample link. I need to keep it as an array filling in each row since locations and workers are added all the time and also used in other array formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in **G:H** range and use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IF(B4:B="Active", C4:C, ), D4:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Nice, I need to read more up on queries. Is it possible to only show what it is returning in Column H in case I don't need the IDs right next to it? My initial thought is to pass it through a second query where I know I can grab just column 2 of the returned.

Comment: sure, remove `Col1,` after `select`

Comment: Was going to mark it complete either way I just don't like jumping the gun mid discussion. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using only a query is now added.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B4:E14},
  "Select Col2, Sum(Col3) 
  Where Col1 is not null and
  Col1 matches 'Active'
  group by Col2
  label Sum(Col3)''"))
```